# dlopen errors in glibc

Tags: c, valgrind, glibc, dlopen

I am trying to debug an issue with dlopen that happens at random times.

I don't have a reproducer for this issue. basically when i run an executable under **valgrind** I get this error occasionally.

my_file.cxx

`line 342: void* h = dlopen( "libstream.so", RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW);`

```
Invalid write of size 2
   at 0x3F4B0184CE: mempcpy (memcpy.S:79)
   by 0x3F4B0059F9: open_path (dl-load.c:1866)
   by 0x3F4B00871B: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2086)
   by 0x3F4B00C381: openaux (dl-deps.c:65)
   by 0x3F4B00E265: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
   by 0x3F4B00CA64: _dl_map_object_deps (dl-deps.c:247)
   by 0x3F4B012B61: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:268)
   by 0x3F4B00E265: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
   by 0x3F4B0125A9: _dl_open (dl-open.c:587)
   by 0x3F4C000F65: dlopen_doit (dlopen.c:67)
   by 0x3F4B00E265: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
   by 0x3F4C00129B: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:164)
 Address 0x7fefccf50 is on thread 1's stack

Syscall param open(filename) points to unaddressable byte(s)
   at 0x3F4B016EB7: open (syscall-template.S:82)
   by 0x3F4B00542F: open_verify (dl-load.c:1638)
   by 0x3F4B005ADA: open_path (dl-load.c:1883)
   by 0x3F4B00871B: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2086)
   by 0x3F4B00C381: openaux (dl-deps.c:65)
   by 0x3F4B00E265: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
   by 0x3F4B00CA64: _dl_map_object_deps (dl-deps.c:247)
   by 0x3F4B012B61: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:268)
   by 0x3F4B00E265: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
   by 0x3F4B0125A9: _dl_open (dl-open.c:587)
   by 0x3F4C000F65: dlopen_doit (dlopen.c:67)
   by 0x3F4B00E265: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
 Address 0x7fefccf50 is on thread 1's stack

Invalid write of size 1
   at 0x3F4B0184BE: mempcpy (memcpy.S:67)
   by 0x3F4B0059F9: open_path (dl-load.c:1866)
   by 0x3F4B00871B: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2086)
   by 0x3F4B00C381: openaux (dl-deps.c:65)
   by 0x3F4B00E265: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
   by 0x3F4B00CA64: _dl_map_object_deps (dl-deps.c:247)
   by 0x3F4B012B61: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:268)
   by 0x3F4B00E265: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
   by 0x3F4B0125A9: _dl_open (dl-open.c:587)
   by 0x3F4C000F65: dlopen_doit (dlopen.c:67)
   by 0x3F4B00E265: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:178)
   by 0x3F4C00129B: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:164)
 Address 0x7fefccf50 is on thread 1's stack
```

I am thinking this is a possible cause 
https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13618

Thanks

Comment: getting an error occassionally is a sure sign that the program is performing some undefined behaviour.  The posted line is correct, so the problem is elsewhere in the code

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce this with a minimal program? I've been seeing a similar error myself. What versions of ld do you have installed?

Comment: I don't have a reproducer. ld version 2.20.51.0.2-5.42.el6 20100205

Comment: I got the same error with line numbers of execution trail. How did it even error in an assembly file! It definitely looks like a bug in glibc 2.12